# How to compare generated types within a ISyntaxContextReceiver

Tags: c#, csharp-source-generator

I've got a .NET 5 source generator, and I'm trying to reliably detect classes that have been marked with a specific attribute, which has been generated as part of the same generator.

The trouble is that I can't find a decent way to compare the types - I've tried a range of different options, but none of them work in all scenarios.

In my generator, I am generating the attribute like this:

```cs
[Generator]
public sealed class AddAttribute1 : ISourceGenerator
{
    public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context) { }

    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        var code = @"
using System;

namespace DependencyReproGenerator.Library.Attributes
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public sealed class CustomAttribute1Attribute : Attribute
    {
        public CustomAttribute1Attribute() { }
    }
}";
        context.AddSource("CustomAttribute1Attribute.generator", SourceText.From(code, Encoding.UTF8));
    }
}
```

In another project, I am referencing the source generator, and using the attribute like this:

```cs
using DependencyReproGenerator.Library.Attributes;

namespace DependencyRepro
{
    [CustomAttribute1]
    public class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

So far, so good.  When I add another source generator, using an `ISyntaxContextReceiver` during initialization, I'm trying to check if the visited node has this attribute, and that's where I'm struggling.

This is my `ISyntaxContextReceiver`:

```cs
class ConstructorGeneratorReceiver : ISyntaxContextReceiver
{
    public void OnVisitSyntaxNode(GeneratorSyntaxContext context)
    {
        if (context.Node is ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclarationSyntax)
        {
            foreach (AttributeSyntax attribute in classDeclarationSyntax
                        .DescendantNodes().OfType<AttributeSyntax>())
            {
                SyntaxToken lastDescendantToken = attribute.DescendantTokens()
                            .Where(p => p.IsKind(SyntaxKind.IdentifierToken)).Last();

                ITypeSymbol lastDescendantTokenType = 
                            context.SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(lastDescendantToken.Parent).Type;

                ITypeSymbol lastDescendantConvertedTokenType = 
                            context.SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(lastDescendantToken.Parent).ConvertedType;


                // TODO: Compare something against the expected type
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can compare the names of the types (e.g., `lastDescendantTokenType.Name == "CustomAttribute1"`), but I'm aware that if another attribute with the same name exists in a different namespace, it will pick that one up too, so ideally, I'd want to compare the namespace of the type as well.

How do I check that the current ClassDeclarationSyntax node has got a specific attribute (including matching on both attribute name and namespace)?